# Can't create ~1.2GB Uint8Array in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, v8

The following JavaScript code:

```
new Uint8Array(1253377279)
```

When ran with `node.js` results in:

```
RangeError: length > kMaxLength
    at repl:1:2
    at REPLServer.self.eval (repl.js:110:21)
    at Interface.<anonymous> (repl.js:239:12)
    at Interface.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Interface._onLine (readline.js:202:10)
    at Interface._line (readline.js:531:8)
    at Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:760:14)
    at ReadStream.onkeypress (readline.js:99:10)
    at ReadStream.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at emitKey (readline.js:1095:12)
```

Which is strange, considering I have 8GB of ram, enough to fill that array several times. I've tried: `--max-old-space-size=1900` to no success. What can I do?

Comment: The stack trace predominently stays in the console functionality.  Perhaps it's unable to display whatever the result would be for a structure that size, rather than having any issue actually allocating it?

Comment: @bishop If I understand correctly, Node.js simply refuses to allocate `Buffer`s over a certain size (that is, `1253377279` is greater than [`0x3fffffff`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/7c0419730b237dbfa0ec4e6fb33a99ff01825a8f/src/smalloc.h#L43)).

Comment: this is actually v8 limitation

Comment: immediate question that kind of needs an answer before any other answers: why? Why do you need a 1.2GB uint8array? What problem are you tackling that makes you think this is a thing you need to do?